# Has anybody seen a file named xingma.db in the home folder of Ubuntu system automatically placed?

Tags: ubuntu

In my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04.1, there is a file called xingma.db which is a sqlite file. I dont know which application has dropped it? Has anybody else seen this behavior. Is it malicious?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu, not programming. It would be a good fit for http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xingma is an IM Engine. You probably installed it or it has come with other packages. It is not malicious as far as i know.